# Ruby - Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, null, jekyll

So, I'm new to Ruby and I'm trying to install [this photo gallery](https://github.com/aerobless/jekyll-photo-gallery) to my Jekyll blog. However, when I'm trying to run

```
jekyll build
```

I get this error message:

```
Liquid Exception: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass in photography/index.html 
jekyll 3.7.2 | Error:  undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

With --trace it points me to:

```
/Users/hal9000/Desktop/Plommonstop/_plugins/jekyll-exiftag-mod.rb:18:in `render': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

But now I don't understand how to proceed. jekyll-exiftag-mod looks like this:

```
require 'exifr/jpeg'

#Based on https://github.com/benib/jekyll-exiftag by Beni Buess (MIT License)
#Edited to work as a Liquid-Block instead of a Liquid-Tag, reads the filename from between the
#brackets. --T.Winter

module Jekyll
  class ExifTag < Liquid::Block

    def initialize(tag_name, params, token)
      super
      @args = self.split_params(params)
    end

    def render(context)
      #abort context.registers[:site].config['source'].inspect
      sources = Array.new(context.registers[:site].config['exiftag']['sources'])
      # first param is the exif tag
      tag = @args[0]

      # if a second parameter is passed, use it as a possible img source
      if @args.count > 1
        sources.unshift(@args[1])
      end

      # the image can be passed as the third parameter
      img = super

      # first check if the given img is already the path
      if File.exist?(img)
        file_name = img
      else
      # then start testing with the sources from _config.yml
        begin
          source = sources.shift
          file_name = File.join(context.registers[:site].config['source'], source, img)
        end until File.exist?(file_name) or sources.count == 0
      end
      # try it and return empty string on failure
      begin
        exif = EXIFR::JPEG::new(file_name)
        return tag.split('.').inject(exif){|o,m| o.send(m)}
      rescue
        "ERROR, EXIF-Tag RB"
      end
    end

    def split_params(params)
      params.split(",").map(&:strip)
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('exiftag', Jekyll::ExifTag)
```

With row 18:

```
sources = Array.new(context.registers[:site].config['exiftag']['sources'])
```

What does it mean with "Undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass?" And what exactly is making this problem occur?

Comment: You are calling a method on a value that is nil...

Comment: either `context.registers` or `context.registers[:site].config` or `context.registers[:site].config['exiftag']` returns `nil` since those are the places you are calling `[]`. you see this method chain is actually interpreted as  `context.registers.[](:site).config.[]('exiftag').[]('sources')`

Comment: ['exiftag']['sources'] this sources value is nil

Comment: @iamcaleberic actually this would raise `TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer` the error must be some method call prior to that like `['exiftag']`

Comment: Yes. I was missing the method call to exiftag (see below). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error could simply mean that you have not set `['exiftag']['sources']` in your config file.

Your config file should have something similar to below (entry1 and entry2 are just examples):

```
exiftag:
  sources:
    - entry1
    - entry2
```

Do note, indentation is important in YAML as well..

Comment: Yes, I hade messed up my config.yml. Re-added exiftag:
 sources:
   - images/photography

And now it is working fine. Thank you and @engineersmnky